# SQL View with Boolean value field

Tags: sql, view, boolean-logic

I have a task ahead of me that really boggles me.

I have a table ***Employee*** in the below format. The *employee_id* is the auto-incremented field that acts as the primary key. The *employee_number* is the ID given to the employee by the company and is unique across the table.

[image]

There is another table called ***Employee_Assignment*** that contains the assignment information of employees to projects. This table will have information of only those employees who have assignments. One employee can have one or more assignments. This table uses the *employee_id* field from ***Employee*** table as the foreign key. Also, the employee's status in each project assignment is determined by the *assignment_status_id* field.

[image]

The ***Assignment_Status*** table is as follows. There are 2 types of 'Active' statuses - Active1 and Active2. Similarly, there are 2 types of 'Inactive' statuses - Inactive1 and Inactive2:
[image]

I want to create a view ***Assignment_Status_View*** that is in the following format:

[image]

The view should list all employees from Employee table and a boolean value that indicates if they are active in any project or not. As new employee come in, new records are added to the ***Employee*** table. Also, for each new project assignment, a new record will be added to ***Employee_Assignment*** table. The view should be able to capture both of these.

The *overall_status* field should show the employees' status across all the project assignments, ie., if the employee has 10 assignments and if he/she is in any of the 2 inactive statuses in all the assignments, then *overall_status* = 0. Similarly, if the employee is in any of the 2 active statuses in at least one project assignment, then *overall_status* = 1.

Any help you could provide me will be much appreciated.

Comment: This sounds pretty straight-forward, what specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: I am having difficulty in adding the overall_status field. Doesn't an sql view require all it's fields to be present in some table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CASE based aggregation can be used to see if there exists at least one active status for employee.

Using `left join` to make sure employees with no record in assignment status also counted.

```
        SELECT E.employee_Number, E.name, T.OverAllStatus  FROM 
        employee E
        JOIN (
            SELECT E.employee_Number, 
                   case when COALESCE(SUM( case when EA.assignment_status_id in ( 1,3)  
                                       then 1 
                                       else 0 
                                       end ),0) >0 
                   then 1 else 0 end as OverAllStatus
            FROM Employee E
            LEFT JOIN Employee_Assignment EA
            ON E.employee_id = EA.employee_id
            GROUP BY E.employee_Number
        ) T
        ON E.employee_Number = T.employee_Number
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Your solution doesn't work because Employee_Assignment table does not contain Employee_Number. Employee_Assignment contains Employee_Id which is not the same as Employee_Number. Employee_Id is auto-generated value whereas Employee_Number is the company provided ID for the employee

Comment: @GuhanMurugesan, your second table shows employee_number, if it is ID , then you should join based on that , which should work.

Comment: Oops... My mistake. I have made the correction to the original post. Employee_Number is present in Employee table, but not in Employee_Assignment table. But the view should contain Employee_Number

Comment: @GuhanMurugesan, you can accept the answer when you get chance

Comment: Sorry, I am fairly new to Stackoverflow. I accepted your answer now. Thanks again